# How do I get the total price of all the items in the basket?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the total price of all the items in the basket?

I want to get the total price of all the items in the cart after adding items in the cart. The price should also increase when the quantity of each item is increased and also decrease when the quantity is decreased. Please help me with that,

The code for the cart class is below.

The cart class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading:
                    Text(item.category + "\n" + "R" + item.price.toString()),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `textField` for total ?

Answer (score 0):

Add price calculation method in your Dish class

```
class Dish{
  int count;
  double price;

  double totalPrice(){
    // add your price calculation logic
    return price * count;
  }
}
```

add the below method in your Cart widget

```
double cartTotalPrice(){
  double total=0;
  _cart.forEach((item) { total += item.totalPrice(); });
  return total;
}
```

Or use the one line solution

```
double total = _cart.map<double>((item) => item.count*item.price).reduce((value1, value2) => value1+value2);
```

Comment: The variable total throws an error that reads **the getter 'total' is not defined for the type dish**

Comment: You can check the working code here [https://dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/9e763dd1fcdef0c9ff06444493b653f3). Make sure you are not overwriting variable name total

Comment: The `_cart.map` in the total method of the cart class now throws an error that says **The instance member '_cart' can't be accessed in an initializer.**